# Unclosed client session. Any solution?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, python-asyncio, discord.py

I'm using the Discord module, to make a discord bot. I'm pretty bad at this, as I started coding not long ago. Well, I'm having some problems setting the prefix for the bot: It says there's an error in the 8th line.. `unclosed client session` and `NameError: name 'command' is not defined` as well.

Here's the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "SUBLIME TEXT PRUEBA.py", line 8, in <module>
client = command.Bot(command_prefix = '!')
NameError: name 'command' is not defined
Unclosed client session
client_session: <aiohttp.client.ClientSession object at 0x0000017638A4F9E8>
```

I'm also going to put the code here...

```
import discord
from discord.ext.commands import Bot
from discord.ext import commands
import asyncio


Client = discord.Client()
client = command.Bot(command_prefix = '!')


@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('bot is redey')

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content == 'keke':
        await client.send_message(message.channel, 'KEKEKEKEKK')
```

Comment: you write command but you import commands (plural). Is that it ?

Comment: and I guess that you have to call something like close() on your discord.Client() object, before your program ends

Comment: @lhk oh well.. Gonna try that.. such a silly mistake if that's the solution hehe

Comment: @Ihk yeah pretty sure thats the issue.

Comment: @lhk yeah, it worked perfectly. Thankss!

Comment: @Owneyy nice :)

Comment: @lhk I'm really ashamed.. As I'm using Sublime Text to code, I forgot to save the changes before running it, so that's why it didn't work at the first time. I knew it'd be a stupid mistake :I oh god hehe

Comment: impotence ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Why are you using both `discord.Client` and `commands.Bot`?  You should use only one of those.

Comment: @PatrickHaugh oh um

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As discussed in the comments:

- you need to use `commands` instead of `command`
- your `discord.Client()` session needs to be closed, probably with a method like `close()`